# How give div that has a background image a percentage height?

Tags: html, css, height, background-image

I have section of icons on my page. 
[image]

However, because I'm using background image, I had to specify a pixel height for the div `.iconImage.linkedIn`. I tried specifying a percentage height, but it didn't work. I want to make this website look good for different resolutions, so how do I give the div with the background image a percentage height while keeping the same functionality of the icons (text and image lights up upon hovering over link) ? ***Please do NOT give me an answer that uses pixels or ems for height/width because I want a website that looks good for different resolutions.***

**HTML:**

```
<div class = "icon">
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank">
        <div class = "iconImage linkedIn"></div>
        <div class = "iconTitle linkedIn">LinkedIn</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.iconImage.linkedIn {
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url('../images/linkedin.png'); 
}

.icon a:hover > .iconImage.linkedIn {
    background-image: url('../images/linkedinhover.png');
}

.icon a:hover > .iconTitle.linkedIn {
    color: rgb(130,130,130);
}
```

Comment: All your parents elements must have a defined height so it takes the height percentage of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'vw' or 'vh' instead of pixels. This works much better than percentages as they are not related to the size of their ancestors, but simply to the viewport size.

```
.iconImage.linkedIn {
     height: 5vh; /* was height: 50px; */
     ...
}
```

See it in action: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QGPwBo

Comment: What is this vw / vh thing? :O

Comment: It is a unit: viewport width or viewport height. The number is a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

- Height and Width percentage units are always defined relative to the
  size of the parent element. (parent height = 500px & child height =
  25% => child height = 250px)
- Padding percentage units are defined relative to the width of the parent
  container.
- A viewport unit is relative to the screen's height/width size. (100vh
  = 100% of viewport height, 100vw = 100% of viewport width)

In your code, the parent element is the anchor tag `<a>`. And by default it only takes as much space as it needs, which right now is the size of `.iconTitle` element.

So to specify a height of 33.33% for the icon, you need to set the height of the parent element first.

Or just specify the icon's `padding` property in percentage unit. That way you only have to worry about width of the parent. (I did this instead of setting height and worked just like you wanted)

Also `background-image` property acts different than `<img>` element. There's no `height/width: auto`. Instead, you must specify both height and width sizes for the div (or just add `padding` as I did) and then set `background-size: contain` so image automatically scales and renders within the specified dimensions without getting chopped.

Lastly, don't forget about the `display` property for all elements. It's crucial in determining the width, and arrangement of your elements.

---

I've corrected your HTML code slightly. I used `<p>` elements for iconTitle.

```css
.iconTitle {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.iconImage.linkedIn {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 3%;
    background-image: url('http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/3c9eaa4c8dd944eade4d976497f7c5e9.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class = "icon">
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank">
        <div class = "iconImage linkedIn"></div>
        <p class = "iconTitle linkedIn">LinkedIn</p>
    </a>
</div>
```